# Segmentation fault installing Kinetic on Raspbian Stretch

Tags: raspberrypi, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to follow instructions here
http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi to install ROS Kinetic on my Raspberry Pi 3B.

I made some progress previously early last week, and this didn't happen. Many packages were successfully built, but the build failed while trying to build `pluginlib`. I decided to try again, did some apt-get updates in the meantime.

Now when I try to follow the instructions again, even after completely deleting the catkin workspace folder and making a new one, I get this right away:

```
~~  - rostopic
~~  - roswtf
~~  - topic_tools
~~  - rosbag
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The packages or cmake arguments have changed, forcing cmake invocation

==> Processing catkin package: 'catkin'
==> Creating build directory: 'build_isolated/catkin'
==> cmake /home/computername/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/computername/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/catkin -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/kinetic -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G Unix Makefiles in '/home/computername/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin'
<== Failed to process package 'catkin':
  Command '['cmake', '/home/computername/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin', '-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/computername/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/catkin', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/kinetic', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-G', 'Unix Makefiles']' returned non-zero exit status -11

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/computername/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin && cmake /home/computername/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/computername/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/catkin -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/kinetic -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G 'Unix Makefiles'

Command failed, exiting.
```

Running the "reproduce this error" command just segfaults:

```
(cv) computername@computername:~/ros_catkin_ws $ cd /home/computername/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin && cmake /home/computername/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/computername/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/catkin -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/kinetic -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G 'Unix Makefiles'
Segmentation fault
(cv) computername@computername:~/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin $
```

I've also tried this outside of the `cv` virtual environment with the same result.

I should probably just scrap the idea of doing it on Raspbian but there's significant config specific to my robot (GPIO dtoverlays, network and DNS config, etc) on my Raspbian install (backed up as well) and I don't want to start over right now. I think I had some kind of networking challenge with Ubuntu Mate that I don't want to tackle.

I might be able to re-set the state and get something else besides the segfault again by going back to an older backup disk image, but I'd also like to understand what is failing here if I can.

Any ideas where I can look? Anyone else having this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/305148/segmentation-fault-installing-kinetic-on-raspbian-stretch/) by [danzimmerman](https://answers.ros.org/users/37963/danzimmerman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 337 on 2018-10-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-08**:
It seems `cmake` segfaults, so I would try and figure out why. Can you run `cmake` by itself (perhaps with some 'toy' project?

How did you install CMake on your system?

**Comment by [danzimmerman](https://answers.ros.org/users/37963/danzimmerman/) on 2018-10-08**:
You're right, cmake just segfaults.

I tried this
https://mirkokiefer.com/cmake-by-example-f95eb47d45b1

I installed with apt-get. I purged it and tried again with apt, following https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/79387/cmake-broken-after-update, but same result.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-08**:
Then it would seem that would be the issue to diagnose. I expect things to start working again if/when you fix the CMake issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like the prebuilt version of cmake I get on the Raspberry Pi with apt or apt-get is quite old, 3.7.something.

I built cmake 3.12.3 from source and that fixed it. I expect pluginlib build will still fail, but we'll deal with that later.

Thanks gvdhoorn.

---

Originally posted by [danzimmerman](https://answers.ros.org/users/37963/danzimmerman/) with karma: 337 on 2018-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-09**:
It could be that the updates you performed to your OS before things failed introduced an ABI break. `SEGFAULT`s are common then.

It would surprise me though as Debian based OS typically guarantee and check ABI compatibility.